# Show a Toaster after a successful login with Auth0 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, oauth-2.0

I was trying to implement my toaster for welcoming logged in users: Everything looks ready but I just need a function that tells the toaster to appear, that is after the user gets redirected to the page they wanted to see before the log in.
Here it is my Login Button and my Toaster Context:

```
export const LoginButton: React.FC = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0();
  const { showToaster } = useToaster();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    await loginWithRedirect();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated && !isLoading) {
      showToaster();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, isLoading, showToaster]);

  return (
    <button
      className="w-full py-2 px-4 rounded-lg hover:bg-[#0B1D32]"
      onClick={handleLogin}
      disabled={isLoading}
    >
      Login
      <i className="fa-solid pl-2 fa-right-to-bracket lg:inline hidden"></i>
    </button>
  );
};
export default LoginButton;
```

```
type ToasterContextType = {
  showToaster: () => void;
  setIsToasterVisible: (value: boolean) => void; // Prenderà un valore booleano quando richiamato
  isToasterVisible: boolean; // Avrà un valore booleano
};

export const ToasterContext = createContext<ToasterContextType | undefined>(
  undefined
);

type ToasterProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

export const ToasterProvider: React.FC<ToasterProviderProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [isToasterVisible, setIsToasterVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const showToaster = () => {
    setIsToasterVisible(true); // Mostra il toaster
    setTimeout(() => setIsToasterVisible(false), 3000); // Hide toaster after 3 seconds
  };

  return (
    <ToasterContext.Provider
      value={{
        showToaster,
        setIsToasterVisible,
        isToasterVisible,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ToasterContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The toaster component is literally just a div so it's not that important

I put the Toaster component inside every page and tried to implement a logic that was supposed to set the Toaster visible after the user was redirected to the login page of Auth0 but that didn't work, after that I tried to tell to show the toaster after the user was authenticated but that didn't help because now the Toaster always shows up in every page. I was looking in the docs if there’s a method that returns true when my user successfully logs in (and get redirected to the page), but I couldn’t find a method or any way that reliably returns me true in this specific situation.
Has anyone has any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to show the toast is in your login function, as there you exactly know the user state, showing toast as a side effect is not the best option as there you're not sure about the exact user state,

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
    await loginWithRedirect();
    showToast();
  };
```

Another option is to use a [toast library](https://react-hot-toast.com/).

You can also use a [lightweight events library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoevents) to fire toast events and listen to them in your root component and show your toaster component.